# Remote Dot net application

Tags: .net, azure

I have heard of remote dot net application.
What I have understood that the application works on the client side, while it's on the server. This mean client can't access code and also need to connect to server to access application.
I'm not sure of that, is that the purpose.
Also does it have a relation with Windows Azure?
some clarifications and links appreciated and thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what your question is. 
But, you might want to look at .NET Remoting, read an article from code project [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Net_Remoting.aspx)

Windows Azure is a cloud based operating systems & offers various .NET Services on the cloud, read [Windows Azure - Breaking It Down](http://www.codethinked.com/post/2009/01/14/Windows-Azure-Breaking-It-Down.aspx) by Justin Etheredge

Answer (score 0):

Here are some forms of remote applications (not sure which you are referring to):

- You can build/run .net applications from network shares (with restrictions)
- click-once, allows you to provide a
  simple installer link on a web page,
  with auto-update capabilities
- silverlight - flash like interface in
  the browser (not quite, but simplest 
  way I found to say it)
- Azzure: you can host .net applications on the net, but that is more around exposing/consuming a variety of services and exposing it on the web (no relation to actually running it remotely like the network share case)

Answer (score 0):

[Azure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Azure) is [cloud computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_platform) which is a step up from [smart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc540671.aspx) [thin clients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_client). Also I'd like to point out that smart thin clients don't have to run in the browser like is very commonly misunderstood.